# find the distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose two teams play a series of games, each producing a winner
and a loser, until one team has won two more games than the other.
Let G be the total number of games played. Assume each team has
a chance of 0.5 to win each game, independent of the results of the
previous games.
(a) Find the probability distribution of G.
(b) Find the expected value of G.

I couldn't make much of a headway so I can't include what I have tried to do?

Comment: A question close to this one [was asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386266/how-i-can-find-the-expected-value-of-g) yesterday. That question did not ask for the distribution, but in a comment OP asked and I answered that part also, but without detail.

Answer (score 1):

We will denote $F_{G}(g)$ as the cdf of $G$.

**Hints:**

1. If $g<2$ then $F_{G}(g)=0$
2. It suffices to find $F_{G}(g)$ for $g=2,3,4\ldots$
3. If the game ends after$g$ turns then in the first $g-2$ games
   we have a tied result (note that the game can't end after an odd number
   of turns)
4. The same team won the last two games